# WPF UserControl Binding - OnPropertyChanged call Function

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls, propertychanged

Good evening!
I have read multiple threads about binding and thought I got the hang of it (at least for textBoxes, ObservableCollections, etc.).
Now however, I have a bit more complicated problem and got lost somewhere:

I created a UserControl (STATUSBOX), containing labels etc.
I am binding those labels like this:

```
 <Label x:Name="c1" x:FieldModifier="private" Grid.Column="1" 
    Grid.Row="1" Height="20" Style="{StaticResource labelTable}" 
    Width="140" Content="{Binding Path= value1}" Margin="0,0,0,0" ></Label>
```

In the code behind, I implemented it like that:

```
public String value1
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(ValueProperty1); }
        set {
                SetValue(ValueProperty1, value); 
                //setLightColor(1, value); //[I]
            }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty1 =
        DependencyProperty.Register("value1", typeof(string),
          typeof(UC_StatusBox_detailed), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

That works just fine.

Now however, I try to add a status light which switches between green-orarnge-red. Therefore, I created a new UserControl (LAMPCONTROL) which displays part of a sprite image:

```
<Border x:Name="frame" x:FieldModifier="private" Width="30" Height="30" Grid.Column="0" 
    Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="4" BorderThickness="1">
    <Rectangle Height="30" Width="30" Grid.Column="0" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush x:Name="imgBrush" x:FieldModifier="private" ViewboxUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="0,0, 30,30" ImageSource="/TestControl;component/Icons/spriteLight.png"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>            
</Border>
```

I added the following method:

```
private void UpdateLightStatus(Boolean statusOK)
    {
        int offset;         
        if (statusOK)
        {
            offset = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            offset = 30;
        }
        this.imgBrush.Viewbox = new Rect(offset, 0, 30, 30);
    }
```

That also works, if I use it "stand alone".

However if I try to implement this in my STATUSBOX, I am having trouble to get it working...
I was hoping to do something like here [I] and all is done, but that does not work.
In the next approach, I tried to create a DependencyProperty in the LAMPCONTROL equal to those in the STATUSBOX and add a binding in the xaml of the LAMPCONTROL and from there on I got a bit confused.

**The question - in short - would be: How to call a method of a sub-UserControl 
from the main-UserControl when the bound property of the main-UserControl is changed?**

I hope it is a bit understandable what my problem is, if more info is required, I am happy to provide that, but I didn't want to make this question even larger than it is now...

Thank you for reading all of that and best regards

Fabian

---

Clemens put me in the right direction. The solution is below

Comment: As a note, you did not adhere to mandatory naming conventions for dependency properties. The identifier field of a `value1` property must be named `value1Property`. The property would however better be named `Value1` and the identifier field `Value1Property`. Besides that, you must not call anything else than SetValue in the property setter. To react on value changes, register a PropertyChangedCallback with the dependency property metadata. Start reading here: [Custom Dependency Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/custom-dependency-properties).

Comment: @Clemens Thank you, that helped a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clemens put me in the right direction. The solution is as follows:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty Value1Property =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Value1", typeof(string),
      typeof(UC_StatusBox_detailed), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
          new PropertyChangedCallback(OnValueChanged)));


private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
//my code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to call a method of a sub-UserControl from the main-UserControl when the bound property of the main-UserControl is changed?

You could give the sub-control an `x:Name` in the XAML markup of the main-control:

```
<local:LampControl x:Name="subControl" />
```

You can then access it using this name in the code-behind of the main-control:

```
subControl.UpdateLightStatus(false);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I already tried that as well, but I didn't find out, where to call the method then... it would be the same problem there... I would love to make the call automatically once the bound property changes...

Comment: @fabi: "Where to call the method then"? In the callback of the dependency property if you want to update the status when this property is changed. Or when do you want to call the method?